# How to call functions in android and iOS swift from javascript in similar way

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, wkwebview

I am trying to call functions in `android` and `iOS Swift`(WKWebview)from `javascript`.

**For Android:**

```
public class WebAppInterface {

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void postMessage(String message) {
        Log.v(TAG, "message ----"+message);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(mContext), "appInterface");
```

**JavaScript call For Android:**

```
window.appInterface.postMessage("Hello);
```

**Javascript call for iOS:**

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.appInterafce.postMeesage("Hello");
```

So, here we are making different calls from `javascript` for `android` and `iOS`.
Is it possible to call functions in both `android` and `iOS` in one single way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Wrap them both up in a single function?

```
function postAppMessage(msg) {
    if (window.webkit != undefined) {
        if (window.webkit.messageHandlers.appInterface != undefined) {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.appInterface.postMessage(msg)
        }
    }
    if (window.appInterface != undefined) {
        window.appInterface.postMessage(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent a whole day to find this simple answer for my same need. You saved my second day.

Comment: whats the swift equivalent for postMessage function?